# Позиционирование и ширина блоков

Tags: css, flexbox

Хочу сделать блоки как 
https://wp-kama.ru/id_7686/miniatyury-dlya-elemetov-taksonomij.html, а именно речь об этом:
[image]

Вот что получилось, но.. не получилось :( : Они сжимаются, а не перекрываются.
Что я упустил, как поправить?

```css
div.inner {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  height: 15em;
  width:800px;
}

figure {
  box-shadow: -0.8em 0 2em -1em #222a2d;
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1em 1em 0;
  transition: flex 300ms cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1) 0s, -webkit-box-flex 300ms cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1) 0s, -ms-flex 300ms cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1) 0s;
}

figure:hover {
  -moz-box-flex: 0.001;
  flex: 0.001 0.001 calc(400px + 2em);
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
<figure><h3 class="widget-price-title">Однажды, в студеную зимнюю пору</h3>
<div class="textwidget"><p>Однажды, в студеную зимнюю пору,<br>
Я из лесу вышел; был сильный мороз.
</p><p>Гляжу, поднимается медленно в гору<br>
Лошадка, везущая хворосту воз.</p></div>
</figure>

<figure><h3 class="widget-price-title">И, шествуя важно</h3>
<div class="textwidget"><p>И, шествуя важно, в спокойствии чинном,<br>
Лошадку ведет под уздцы мужичок<br>
</p><p>В больших сапогах, в полушубке овчинном,<br>
В больших рукавицах... а сам с ноготок!<br>
</p></div>
</figure>

<figure><h3 class="widget-price-title">Здорово, парнище!</h3>
<div class="textwidget"><p>— Здорово, парнище!— «Ступай себе мимо!»<br>
— Уж больно ты грозен, как я погляжу!<br>
</p><p>Откуда дровишки?— «Из лесу, вестимо;<br>
Отец, слышишь, рубит, а я отвожу».<br>
</p></div>
</figure>

<figure><h3 class="widget-price-title">В лесу раздавался топор дровосека</h3>
<div class="textwidget"><p>(В лесу раздавался топор дровосека.)<br>
— А что, у отца-то большая семья?<br>
</p><p>«Семья-то большая, да два человека<br>
Всего мужиков-то: отец мой да я...»...
</p></div>
</figure>
</div>
```

Код: http://www.cssdesk.com/Dmusw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно задать минимальную ширину для вложенных элементов тега `figure`

```css
.widget-price-title,
.textwidget {
  min-width: 400px;
}

div.inner {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  height: 15em;
  width:800px;
}

figure {
  box-shadow: -0.8em 0 2em -1em #222a2d;
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1em 1em 0;
  transition: flex 300ms cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1) 0s, -webkit-box-flex 300ms cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1) 0s, -ms-flex 300ms cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1) 0s;
}

figure:hover {
  -moz-box-flex: 0.001;
  flex: 0.001 0.001 calc(400px + 2em);
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
<figure><h3 class="widget-price-title">Однажды, в студеную зимнюю пору</h3>
<div class="textwidget"><p>Однажды, в студеную зимнюю пору,<br>
Я из лесу вышел; был сильный мороз.
</p><p>Гляжу, поднимается медленно в гору<br>
Лошадка, везущая хворосту воз.</p></div>
</figure>

<figure><h3 class="widget-price-title">И, шествуя важно</h3>
<div class="textwidget"><p>И, шествуя важно, в спокойствии чинном,<br>
Лошадку ведет под уздцы мужичок<br>
</p><p>В больших сапогах, в полушубке овчинном,<br>
В больших рукавицах... а сам с ноготок!<br>
</p></div>
</figure>

<figure><h3 class="widget-price-title">Здорово, парнище!</h3>
<div class="textwidget"><p>— Здорово, парнище!— «Ступай себе мимо!»<br>
— Уж больно ты грозен, как я погляжу!<br>
</p><p>Откуда дровишки?— «Из лесу, вестимо;<br>
Отец, слышишь, рубит, а я отвожу».<br>
</p></div>
</figure>

<figure><h3 class="widget-price-title">В лесу раздавался топор дровосека</h3>
<div class="textwidget"><p>(В лесу раздавался топор дровосека.)<br>
— А что, у отца-то большая семья?<br>
</p><p>«Семья-то большая, да два человека<br>
Всего мужиков-то: отец мой да я...»...
</p></div>
</figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё почти класс, кроме последнего блока. Он тоже становиться обрезанным, как и остальные. Не затруднит ли поправить этот момент?

Comment: @Вася Не пойму о чем. Можно поподробнее.

Comment: В последнем блоке обрезано содержимое https://i.imgur.com/5Dw2a5w.jpg Хотелось бы что бы оно было развернуто по умолчанию https://i.imgur.com/Mfxl8Dp.jpg и сворачивалось когда hover на др блоках.  ... {Пока это писал - кажется начал понимать как это сделать :) Но всё равно  буду благодарен за помощь.. для контроля и понимания правильности моих потуг.}

Comment: @Вася у вас ширина inner` **800px**, изначально блоки `figure` занимают по **20%** (160px) от размеров `inner`, а дочерние блоки `figure` больше чем эти **20%** из за чего они выглядят обрезаными.

Answer (score 0):

```
figure > * {
 min-width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. К сож низкая моя репа не даёт  возможности поставить плюсик.